# SQL Count rows in another table and join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 table in my database. The first is `comments` and the other is `comments_votes`. 
I want to select all comments, and for each comment, select all it's votes from `comments_votes`, add them up together and join it with the first query as totalVote.

My `comments` table look like:

```
id      comment      video_id   date_sent
----------------------------------------
5      "...."           99        "2017-05-23"
18      "...."          99        "2017-05-23"
```

`comments_votes` table look like:

```
id      user_id      comment_id   vote
----------------------------------------
45         86           5         1
45         23           5         1
78         12            18        -1
```

And the final wished result would look like:

```
id      comment   video_id   votes_total
----------------------------------------
5      " ... "      99             2
18      "... "      99           -1
```

I can manage simple SQL operations but this is beyond me. Is something like this even possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`, `JOIN`.

Comment: Your data has a problem.  Nowhere does a `video_id` of `124` appear in the source data.  Maybe this is a typo?

Comment: Hint: `SUM`....

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Corrected my typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select C.id, C.Comment, C.Video_ID, SUM(V.Votes) AS Vote_total 
from comments C 
left outer join comments_votes V 
on C.id=V.comment_id
group by C.id, C.Comment, C.Video_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.id,comment,c.video_id,SUM(v.vote) AS Vote_total 
FROM comments c, comments_votes v
WHERE c.id = v.comment_id
GROUP BY C.id, C.Comment, C.Video_ID;
```

Comment: This used the old style Oracle join and also I believe you are doing an inner join and not an outer join.